# Send contents of div via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a div that is editable, I would like to be able to send its contents as a post variable without a page refresh. How can I do this with use of Ajax? I can't use jquery.form.js as it requires form elements...

Cheers

```
<div id="edit" onClick="this.contentEditable='true';">
    lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum dolor
</div>
```

Comment: Why that `onClick` business and not just the `contenteditable` attribute? Also, `'true'` is something you should fix now.

Comment: Sorry, just threw it together. Needed it to be editable only on click.

Answer (score 2):

```
<button id="send">Send</button>

$('#send').click(function() {
  var content = $('#edit').text();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'url',
    data: { data: content }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("document").on("blur","#edit", function(){

    $.ajax({
        url:'yourulr',
        data: {data:$(this).html()}
       //other parameters
    });

});
```

Comment: without clicking anything how this will be processed??

Comment: @Jai he asked how to send data, not how to send data when it is clicked. The intersting event is not click but blur in this condition